# App crashes by opening spinner on popup

Tags: java, android, popup, android-spinner

I got a massive problem with my spinner. My popup appears without any problem and it's showing my spinner in closed position.
[image]

But when I open it, my app crashes with following error message...

```
04-10 08:34:33.773    1690-1690/com.example.paul_io E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.paul_io, PID: 1690
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@52f02170 is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:532)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1019)
        at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:925)
        at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:625)
        at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:1110)
        at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:658)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I´ve done wrong?

significant code:

```
  Variables.mainActivity = MainActivity.this;
.
.
.  ​
  Activity mContext = Variables.mainActivity;
  Spinner ecb = new Spinner(mContext);
```

Comment: where is your code???

Comment: @prototype0815 please see my answer & verify.I am very sad to see the downvote gained

Comment: Post your code to get solution... Di you use AsyncTask to load the data to spinner??

Comment: I think that Don Chakkappan gave the right answer. You use wrong context. It may be application context or context of inactive Activity. it is impossible to say more without code.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for dowvoting ! Next time I'll post all the unnecessary code wich is distributed all over my project and wich belongs to my problem.

Comment: And where you use mContext = Variables.mainActivity? If not in the MainActivity or not in inner classes of MainActivity, then this is mistake

Comment: I use mContext at each fragment, wich is displayed at my mainActivity. This works always fine...

Answer (score 1):

The **problem is with your Context** passed (`BadTokenException`).

I think your using `getApplicationContext()`.Instead that use `YourActivityName.this` where you are passing `context`

Comment: You stole my answer even before i wrote it... how did you do that?

Comment: I was about to write the same answer ....  Maybe you came from the future after looking my answer and now posted it before me....

Comment: a timetravel,only to annoy you Salmaan? xD ... @Don Chakkappan - I've never done it differently...